# Show `.map` files under their respectives files in WebStorm/IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, file-watcher

Using Filewatchers it's possible to show a generated file under it's respective source file:

[image]
The problem I am having is that only the generated `.js`file is 'watched' and grouped whilst the `.map` file still shows up separately. Is there a way to set it up so that both files are shown under their respective source file?

Comment: Not sure... might be worth filing a feature request on http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Guess I will have to then, was hoping that I was just being stupid O:) . Mulțumesc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your file watcher settings accordingly. Please make sure to set `'Output paths to refresh'` to `'$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.map'`